# A simple tool to monitor and trace my app

Tags: windows-services, monitoring

I have developed an app that runs as a windows service and regularly does a few tasks like synchronizing data sources and generating some statistics. I want to:

1) Get sms when the service stops for any reason. I don't want to deploy a fully fledged infrastructure monitoring system (like nagios).

2) Other people in my team (and possibly other teams) to get customized notifications (by email) if the generated metrics/statistics meet their criteria. This should be a self-service, I don't want to re-configure my app each time someone wants to subscribe to events.

Do you know a tool that can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at [AlertGrid](http://alert-grid.com) service. It has features you need (and even more). Your service will require integration with AlertGrid but this is very simple (there are also some [code samples](http://alert-grid.com/documentation/integration-code-samples/#csharp) ).